# How do I access the definitions key that is nested inside multiple levels of arrays and dictionaries of the Oxford Dictionaries API?

Tags: json, swift, api, dictionary

I am a student in an iOS Swift app development class at my high school. I am trying to access the definitions key in the Oxford English Dictionary API, which is nested inside of multiple arrays and dictionaries. I have accessed data that is inside the "lexicalEntries" key, but I am not able to work any further inside the API.

I have tried many different methods in my attempts to unwrap the data, but none have worked. Commented out are some of the techniques that I have attempted to utilize, which I include to give some context.

```
func parse() {
    let word_id = word.lowercased()
    let url = URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/\(language)/\(word_id)")!
    //        let word = id
    //        let otherDefinitions = subsenses
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
    request.addValue(appKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    _ = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        if let response = response,
            let data = data,
            let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject] {
            //                print(response)
            //                print(jsonData)
            //                print(jsonData["results"] as Any)
            //                print(jsonData["entries"] as Any) // does not work
            //

            let results = jsonData["results"] as? [JSONDictionary]
            // let entries = jsonData["entries"] as Any //does not work
            for result in results! {
                print(result)
            }
            //working through entries level
            //                let lexicalEntries = results?["lexicalEntries"] as? [String:String]
            //                print(lexicalEntries)
            //                let entries = jsonData["entries"] as Any
            //                let senses = jsonData["senses"] as Any
            //                let definitions = jsonData["definitions"] as Any
            //                print(entries)
        } else {
            print(error ?? print("default Value Called"))
            print(NSString.init(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

        }
    }).resume()
}
```

During all my attempts, the only nested data that I have been able to parse was "lexicalEntries." I couldn't work past that point to access the definitions key inside the API.

Picture of API Structure:
[image: Picture of API Structure]

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding in Swift 4 or later you should use Codable protocol and structure the data returned by the API.

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let metadata: Metadata
    let results: [Result]
}
struct Metadata: Codable {
    let provider: String
}
struct Result: Codable {
    let id: String
    let language: String
    let lexicalEntries: [Lexical]
}
struct Lexical: Codable {
    let entries: [Entry]
}
struct Entry: Codable {
    let etymologies: [String]?
    let grammaticalFeatures: [Feature]
    let homographNumber: String
    let senses: [Sense]
}
struct Feature: Codable {
    let text: String
    let type: String
}
struct Sense: Codable {
    let definitions: [String]
    let domains: [String]?
    let examples: [Example]
    let id: String
    let short_definitions: [String]
}
struct Example: Codable {
    let registers: [String]?
    let text: String
}
```

---

Then you can easily parse your JSON data response:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let wordId = "Ace"
let url = URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/en/\(wordId)")!
let appId = "********"
let appKey = "********************************"
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.addValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
request.addValue(appKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
    do {
        let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
        let results = root.results
        for result in results {
            for lexical in result.lexicalEntries {
                for entry in lexical.entries {
                    for sense in entry.senses {
                        for definition in sense.definitions {
                            print(definition)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
}.resume()
```

---

This will print

> a playing card with a single spot on it, ranked as the highest card in its suit in most card games
>
> a person who excels at a particular sport or other activity
>
> (in tennis and similar games) a service that an  opponent is unable to return and thus wins a point.
>
> a person who has no sexual feelings or desires
>
> very good
>
> (of a person) having no sexual feelings or desires, asexual
>
> (in tennis and similar games) serve an ace against (an opponent)
>
> achieve high marks in (a test or exam)